# Regex/PHP to grab numbers between a hash and any non-number?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of text and within it are several instances that are always a hash and then a number (and then sometimes punctuation), eg:

> Text **#12321**, Text **#456** Text **#789**; Text **#0**! Etc.

I need regex to preg_match_all every number (variable lengths) following a hash but before anything not a number - so in the above example I'd get an array of:

> '**12321**' '**456**' '**789**' '**0**'

I tried:

```
'/[#](.*?)[^0-9]/'
```

and

```
'/(\\d+)(.*?)(\\d+)/'
```

but the first failed in a bizarre way and the second only matches every other instance.

I'm trying to puzzle my way through documentation but it would help so much to see how best to do this. Could anyone save a me hours of confusion and tell me the correct regex syntax for this?

Comment: this should work '/\d+/'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regex: -

```
'/#(\d+)/'
```

You don't need to check for `non-number` at the end. `\d+` will only get you digits anyways, and will stop as soon as a *non-digit* is encountered.

Note that `#` is not a meta character in regex, so you don't need to enclose it in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt listed:

```
'/[#](.*?)[^0-9]/'
```

seems like it would fail only because it consumes an extra character, which may be the beginning of the next match (if you had a string like "#123#456").  It's pretty close, but this:

```
'/#([0-9]+)/'
```

should work just fine, I believe.